# How can I use fread() to load the contents of a file into the second element of an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers, fread

I am having some trouble understanding how pointers work in a particular situation. The details of my confusion are outlined below.

I have created a character array of 8-byte strings named buffer and I am trying to use fread() to load 8 bytes from a file into one of the elements of this array of 8-byte strings.

The contents of my file located at /c/file.txt are simply: TESTTEST

I want the program to load TESTTEST into buffer[1] instead of the value ijklmnop, nothing more.

I know that buffer is really an array of pointers, which in this case are just three consecutive memory addresses that contain the addresses of the first element of three consecutive byte arrays that are not null terminated.

I visualize this as literally 24 memory addresses in a row containing the binary values of ABCDEFGHijklmnopQRSTUVWX without a \0 at the end.

The address of buffer[0] points to an address that points to A, the address of buffer[1] points to an address that points to i, the address of buffer[2] points to an address that points to Q.

I see the fread() to &buffer[1] as reading the 8 bytes into the location at the address stored in buffer[1].

I have tried various attempts at this fread() using &buffer+1, buffer+1, (buffer+1) and so on, but most have given me segmentation faults; &buffer[1] seems to almost do what I want.

Attempting to do a printf("buffer[1] as %%s is %s\n", buffer[1]); near the end before fclose() I get a segmentation fault.

I am close to achieving an understanding, but something just isn't quite right and I am not grasping some fundamental concept that I need to.

I am not sure if terminating (buffer+1)[8] spills over into the first address of buffer[2] or what effect that is having at all.

I am just a little confused in general and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Here is my entire program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c[] = "OFFONOFF";
    char *buffer[] = {"ABCDEFGH", "ijklmnop", "QRSTUVWX"};
    char *t;

    printf("the value in file /c/file.txt is TESTTEST, only those 8 bytes\n");
    printf("the ls listing for /c/file.txt shows 9, I am not sure where the other character comes from\n");

    printf("the value as %%s of buffer[0] is %s\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("the value as %%s of buffer[1] is %s\n", buffer[1]);
    printf("the value as %%s of buffer[2] is %s\n", buffer[2]);
    printf("the sizeof(buffer[2]) is %d\n", sizeof(buffer[2]));

    fp = fopen("/c/file.txt", "r");
    fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0);

    printf("the value as %%c of buffer[1][3] is %c\n", buffer[1][3]);
    printf("the memory address as %%p for  buffer+1 is %p\n", buffer+1);

    fread(&buffer[1], strlen(c), 1, fp);

    /* I am attempting to terminate the fread into &buffer[1] with a \0, removing this doesn't change much */
    (buffer+1)[8] = "\0";

    printf("the memory addreses below are all in %%p format\n");
    printf("the memory address of buffer is %p\n", buffer);
    printf("memory address of buffer[1] is %p\n", buffer[1]);
    printf("memory address of &buffer is %p\n", &buffer);
    printf("memory address of &buffer+1 is %p\n", &buffer+1);
    printf("memory address of &buffer[1] is %p\n", &buffer[1]);
    printf("memory address of buffer is %p\n", buffer);
    printf("memory address of buffer[15] is %p\n", buffer[15]);
    printf("memory address of buffer+15 is %p\n", buffer+15);
    printf("memory address of *(buffer+1) is %p\n", *(buffer+1));
    printf("the sizeof(buffer[0]) is %d\n", sizeof(buffer[0]));
    printf("the sizeof(*(buffer+1)) is %d\n", sizeof(*(buffer+1)));
    printf("the sizeof(buffer) is %d\n", sizeof(buffer));
    printf("the value of *(buffer+0) as %%s is %s\n", *(buffer+0));
    printf("the value of *buffer, the first element of the array of strings, as %%s is %s\n", *buffer);
    printf("the value of buffer+1, the first element of the array of strings, as %%s is %s\n", buffer+1);
    printf("buffer[0] as %%s is %s\n", buffer[0]);
    printf("buffer+1 as %%s is %s\n", buffer+1);
    printf("buffer[2] as %%s is %s\n", buffer[2]);
    printf("buffer is %s\n", buffer+1);
    printf("sizeof(*buffer) is %d\n", sizeof(*buffer));

    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
}
```

Here is the exact output:

```
the value in file /c/file.txt is TESTTEST, only those 8 bytes
the ls listing for /c/file.txt shows 9, I am not sure where the other character comes from
the value as %s of buffer[0] is ABCDEFGH
the value as %s of buffer[1] is ijklmnop
the value as %s of buffer[2] is QRSTUVWX
the sizeof(buffer[2]) is 8
the value as %c of buffer[1][3] is l
the memory address as %p for  buffer+1 is 0x7ffff7b23a28
the memory addreses below are all in %p format
the memory address of buffer is 0x7ffff7b23a20
memory address of buffer[1] is 0x5453455454534554
memory address of &buffer is 0x7ffff7b23a20
memory address of &buffer+1 is 0x7ffff7b23a38
memory address of &buffer[1] is 0x7ffff7b23a28
memory address of buffer is 0x7ffff7b23a20
memory address of buffer[15] is 0x400674
memory address of buffer+15 is 0x7ffff7b23a98
memory address of *(buffer+1) is 0x5453455454534554
the sizeof(buffer[0]) is 8
the sizeof(*(buffer+1)) is 8
the sizeof(buffer) is 24
the value of *(buffer+0) as %s is ABCDEFGH
the value of *buffer, the first element of the array of strings, as %s is ABCDEFGH
the value of buffer+1, the first element of the array of strings, as %s is TESTTEST

@
buffer[0] as %s is ABCDEFGH
buffer+1 as %s is TESTTEST

@
buffer[2] as %s is QRSTUVWX
buffer is TESTTEST

@
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `fread(&buffer[1], strlen(c), 1, fp);` seems to overwrite the pointer itself.

It seems what you want is a two-dimensional array rather than an array of pointers to string literals (which are read-only on most modern platforms, by the way: `char *abc="abc"; abc[0]='d'` usually segfaults) :

```
char buffer[][9] = {"ABCDEFGH", "ijklmnop", "QRSTUVWX"};
```